# Submit form to different action with typo3 flow

Tags: php, fluid, typo3-flow

I have a page with a form for creating users. A user has an hobby, which can be created on the same page by clicking on the second button which opens the page for creating a hobby. After creating the hobby, the previous user form should be shown with the user input inserted before going to the hobby page.

Is there a way to do something like with typo3 flow / fluid without using AJAX?

I tried to submit the input to a different action by clicking on the createHobby button --> The action redirects to the new hobby page, where the user can create the hobby and after creation it should redirect back to the user form with the already filled out input fields by the user .

I used...

```
<input type='submit' value='Create' formaction='/hobby/create' />`
```

to achive this, but it seems there are some problems with the uris... I get following error:

```
#1301610453: Could not resolve a route and its corresponding URI for the given parameters.
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the using the attribute `formaction` is not a good solution for every case, as it is not supported by **IE < 10** as you can [see here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_formaction.asp). I think a JavaScript backport should also be considered (dynamically change the `action` attribute of the form when clicking on the second button, before actually submitting the form).

Concerning your error, you should **not – and probably never – use direct HTML input**, instead try to focus on Fluid ViewHelpers, which allow TYPO3 to create the correct HTML input.

Try this instead:

```
<f:form.submit value="Create" additionalAttributes="{formaction: '{f:uri.action(controller: \'hobby\', action: \'create\')}'}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still get an error while submitting to the action `public function createAction(Hobby $newHobby, User $user){ 
` --> In my view I have tried to send the parameters as hidden fields like `this <f:form.hidden name="user" value="{user}"/> ` and later as additionalParams="{user: '{user}'} --> for both I get the above error. Only calling $this->request->getArgument('user'); seems to work ... removing the hidden fields and addionalParmas, but I get not the complete project... only the id.

Comment: With ```$this->request->getArgument``` you only get the id, after the initializeAction (or the forward action) the id is transformed to the object.

The error above says that the controller and action in the url cannot be resolved. As @Romain Canon wrotes, URL has to be generated by fluid viewhelper, otherwise you can not be sure to get the correkt url. I recommend to review you template and use the viewhelper to create your form.

Comment: Indeed, you should never decide for the framework which URI should be used for a given controller/action. The error you get is the perfect example of why you should not.
Please try to use [this ViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/master/Uri/ActionViewHelper.html), and tell us if you still have the issue.

Comment: Thanks guys. It seems to work with the view helper, but I still can't get parameters to the action. I am doing this in my view: `<f:form id="createHobby" controller="hobby" action="create" class="form-horizontal" objectName="newHobby" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" arguments="userInput: '{userInput}'}">` and this in the controller     `/**
     * @param Hobby $newHobby
     * @param User|null $userInput
     */public function createAction(Hobby $newHobby, User $userInput = null){`
var_dump of $userInput returns null ....

Comment: Okay I think I got it. The params need to be passed using the view helper not arguments / additionalParams in the f:form. Like this:     `<f:form.submit value="Create" additionalAttributes="{formaction: '{f:uri.action(controller: \'hobby\', action: \'create\', additionalParams: {paramExample: \'HelloIamAString\'})}'}" />`

Comment: This seems to work for strings, but not if doing this in the view:    `<f:form.submit value="Create" additionalAttributes="{formaction: '{f:uri.action(controller: \'hobby\', action: \'create\', additionalParams: {userInput: \'{userInput}\'})}'}" />` --> Leads to`#1301610453: Could not resolve a route and its corresponding URI for the given parameters.` again... Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an `$this->forward(...)` in an `initializeAction`depending on an param of your action.

Lets imagine your default Form action is "create". So you need an `initializeCreateAction`:

```
public function initializeCreateAction()
{
  if ($this->arguments->hasArgument('createHobby')) {
    $createHobby = $this->request->getArgument('createHobby');
    if ($createHobby) {
      $this->forward('create', 'Hobby', NULL, $this->request->getArguments());
    }
  }
}
```

Now you must name your input `createHobby` and assign your `createAction` this param:

In fluid:

```
<f:form.button type="submit" name="createHobby" value="1">Create Hobby</f:form.button>
```

In your Controller:

```
public function createAction($formData, $createHobby = false)
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mixed your solution with the solution of Romain Canon.... I still get an error while submitting to the action `public function createAction(Hobby $newHobby, User $user){` --> In my view I have tried to send the parameters as hidden fields like this `<f:form.hidden name="user" value="{user}"/>` and later as additionalParams="{user: '{user}'} --> for both I get the above error. Only calling $this->request->getArgument('user'); seems to work ... removing the hidden fields and addionalParmas, but I get not the complete project... only the id

Answer (score 0):

can you explain something more ... what you show has nothing to do with typo3, I don't know where you inserted that, what version of typo3 , using any extension extra ?